# "label.error" seems to always be present on every bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I can't figure out why `$('label.error')` is showing up on every bootstrap tab when that particular element should only show on 1 tab.  I have a field that's not passing validation on a bootstrap tab and thus a `label` with `class` error is being appended the DOM on the violating field.  But, I can't seem to get my code to land on the specific tab that has the violating field.  What am I doing wrong in the code below? `isErrorPresent` should only be true on 1 particular tab but EVERY tab is showing it to be true...

```
$("#" + formId).validate({ignore:""}).form(); // ignore:"" allows for hidden fields to be validated as well

    $(".tab-content").find("div.tab-pane").each(function (index, tab) {
        var id = $(tab).attr("id");
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').click();

        alert('processing tab ' + id);

        var isErrorPresent = $('div.tab-pane, div.active').find('label.error').length > 0;

        alert(isErrorPresent);

//        if (isErrorPresent) {
//            alert("label.error detected...");
//            hasError = true;
//            return false; // Break .each loop and return to page
//        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with @Red2678's help (thanks)...here's what's working for me now...

```
    // Check all tabs for errors & show first tab that has errors
    $(".tab-content").find("div.tab-pane").each(function (index, tab) {
        var id = $(tab).attr("id");
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').click();

        $("#" + formId).validate().form();

        var activeTab = $('div.tab-pane.active');

        var isErrorPresent = false;
        if ($(activeTab).find('label.error').length > 0) {
            isErrorPresent = $(activeTab).find('label.error').css('display') !== 'none';
        }

        if (isErrorPresent) {
            hasError = true;
            return false; // Break .each loop and return to page
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more markup, this is what I am thinking:

You are doing this:

```
var isErrorPresent = $('div.tab-pane, div.active').find('label.error').length > 0;
```

The selector has a comma in it, meaning you want to checking on **div.tab-pane** && **div.active**

Is that what you wanted? Maybe you meant to do this (no comma and no space):

```
var isErrorPresent = $('div.tab-pane.active').find('label.error').length > 0;
```

Comment: An active bootstrap tab has both of those classes...html looks like `<div class=tab-pane active>`